# catch 404 error spring boot to return custom html

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How can i catch 404 error in application and render a custom html like index.html? i don't want to use a page inside the /error folder.

for example if i'm asking for http://localhost:8080/test and there is no mapping for test, my application should render index.html inside the /resources/template folder

Thanks

****EDIT****

kinda solved this way, the bad thing is that i can't change the path for request mapping even changing the getErrorPath return value.

```
@Controller
public class MyCustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        return "globalerrorview";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using thymeleaf / similiar library for templating ?

Comment: @akhilRao yes sorry, added as tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the custom error page. One easy way is using `/resources/public/error/404.html` which is not desired in your case.

Option:1 
Could you try configuring [ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html).

```
application.properties
    spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
----------------------
@ControllerAdvice
class YourApplicationExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)  // 404
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleNoHandlerFoundException() {
        return new ModelAndView("viewName");
    }
}
```

Option 2:
If you have any other path defined for the error you can simply change the /error path. In your Controller define the corresponding path mapping and route to the custom view.

```
server.error.path=/yourcustomerrorpath
```

Option 3: Using ErrorController

```
@Controller
public class MyCustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        return "globalerrorview";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Haran i've tryed, but looks like nothing happn, i've also tryed to log something inside the function but looks like it's not used

Comment: saw that with controllerAdvice this give me: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

Comment: Not sure about your exact requirement on whether you want to show error pages specific to codes (401,404,403). For global /error path you could try option 3.

Comment: i've already tryed with option 3 before asking, but looks like getErrorPath is not even called, i've tryed to put a log insede it but nothing happn....

Comment: ok, so, looks like getErrorPath is not working,if i return "/" instead "/error" nothing happn, it will alsways search for /error